# How can I capture all outgoing requests to a port to a port on my local machine?

Tags: java, windows, redirect, port, capture

I'd like to capture all attempts to connect on port 11111 and redirect them to a java application running on my local machine.

I'm planning on using this to map web requests.

So I'm wanting to type http://google.com:11111 into my browser.

Then have that request get redirected to my local app running on port 11111. My local app will need to know the url requested.

I'm running a windows 7 PC so need a windows (not linux) solution.

EDIT: Extra info.

The reason I'm wanting this is I want to be able to access a bunch of intranet web services over a http-tunnel. I'd like to be able to do http://someintranetserver:11111 from my home machine and have it routed over the tunnel. The proxy I'm talking through does not support the CONNECT method.

EDIT: More info.

The program I'm trying to redirect all requests to is a java app I'm working on, so ideally I'd like a java solution to this problem.

If java is incapable of doing this a third party app that can redirect to my local app will suffice.

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: This isn't a Java question. You might consider revising your tags to focus more on the people you want help from, which would be Windows users.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: Is there no java way to do this?

Comment: My point is that Java seems irrelevant to your question. You're talking about reconfiguring either Windows, your network card, or some other network device to relay traffic differently than it normally does. If you think Java is somehow involved, then maybe I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart: My ideal solution would be to add some java code to my project so that when my java app starts it captures all attempts to connect to external servers on port X. If java is incapable of doing this then I'll use some other tool, but some java code is my preferred solution.

Comment: I see. Given that Java can execute any arbitrary command via java.lang.Process, then yes, you could probably do this with Java by executing an appropriate OS command. Given that you're targeting Windows, I'd give it even odds that you'll have to restart before the kind of change you're talking about will take effect. I think you could do it without much trouble (or restarts) on Linux. Other than that, and taking into account that I don't do a lot of heavy networking with Java, I'm pretty confident you won't get anything like this working in pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest solution would be to setup an HTTP proxy and route all http traffic through it.  In windows you can setup the proxy directly on your network connection in the control panel.  Firefox / chrome might have their own settings.  As for a proxy implementation in Java, google around for it.  There are tons.  Like this one:  http://dev.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/

This is probably not what you were hoping for.  I am not sure Java would be able to solve this in the manner you want-- you likely need to use C# or something that has easier access to OS internals.

Perhaps you can expand on *why* you want to do this... maybe there is a better, easier way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: I might be able to thieve bits of code from this project if I get stuck. I was hoping to do it without implementing an actual http proxy as it would be nice if I could support non web traffic too.